# Assign value of existing column to new columns in pandas based on conditions

Tags: python, dataset, pandas, data, data-cleaning

I am trying to create a new column in pandas data frame based on existing columns.

| column1 | column2 | column3 | y1 | y2 | y3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 300 | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| 100 | 200 | 300 | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 |
| 100 | 200 | 300 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 |

I want a new columns **vals** which take values of **col1 if currentyear = y1 and col2 if currentyear = y2**

| column1 | column2 | column3 | y1 | y2 | y3 | Vals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 300 | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 | 200 |
| 100 | 200 | 300 | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 | 100 |
| 100 | 200 | 300 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 | 300 |

I am trying below code :

```
    def assignvalues(df):
        if df['y1'] == currentyear:
            df['Vals'] = df['col1']
        elif df['y2'] == currentyear:
            df['Vals'] = df['col2']
        elif df['y3'] == currentyear:
            df['Vals'] = df['col3']
```

```
df.apply(assignvalues)
```

It does create columns but doesn't store any values.

Answer (score 1):

No the cleanest solution but it works

```
currentyear = 2021

df["Vals"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["column1"] if x["y1"] == currentyear else x["column2"] if x["y2"] == currentyear else x["column3"], axis = 1)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
df['vals'] = [x1 if y1 == currentyear else x2 if y2 == currentyear for x1, x2, y1, y2 in zip(df['col1'],df['col2'],df['y1'],df['y2'])]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, however it doesn't recognize multiple variables in for loop and gives syntax error

`df['GPEUR'] = [x1 if y1 == currentyear else x2 if y2 == currentyear for x1, x2, y1, y2 in zip(df['y_1grossprofiteur'],df['y2grossprofiteur'],df['y_1'],df['y2'])]
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: I don't know then... You should directly post this question to Stack Overflow, since that's directly code-related